# How to Place a xaml Control in windows phone to display in a secondary tile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I want create a secondary tile for my windows phone app, which Displays the Control in my Mainpage, For example, how to Display a Panel control(which Consists image inside) to display in the secondary tile.

```
    public void CreateSecondaryTile()
    {
        ShellTile secTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("MainPage.xaml"));
        if (secTile == null)
        {
            StandardTileData fullTile = new StandardTileData()
            {
                //'*** Primary Tile Properties ***
                BackgroundImage = new Uri(controlName, UriKind.Relative),
                Count = DateTime.Now.Second,
                Title = "Front Title",

                //'*** Secondary Tile Properties ***
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Background.png", UriKind.Relative),
                BackContent = "Back Content",
                BackTitle = "Back Title"
            };
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), fullTile);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To generate Image from your control

> ///  /// Performs rendering and storing image /// 
>   /// Rendering UIElement /// Uri to store image private static void
>   RenderAndStoreImage(UIElement element, string uri) {  try     {       var
>   writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
>         writeableBitmap.Render(element, new TranslateTransform());
>
> ```
>   using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
>   {           using (var stream = store.OpenFile(uri, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
>       {
>           writeableBitmap.Invalidate();
>           writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, 173, 173, 0, 100);             }       }   }   catch (Exception ex)    {       Logger.Log(ex);     }
> ```
>
> }

To create secondary tile

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/How-to-add-and-remove-Secondary-Tiles-in-Windows-Phone-apps

Comment: Cna we Place a mosaic tile inside as Secondary tile which looks like people tile in windows phone. .

Comment: No, you are restricted by reference to the image. But you can try to generate/update this image from background worker to have it look mosaic. In Windows Phone 8 there will be more options.

Comment: Well, Thanks For your Reply! I Understand the Scenario Sir. . . Please Vote for my question, if you consider, this is useful. . .